# Upper bound of a recursive sequence for a fixed $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a recursive sequence given by $$x_n = \sqrt{\frac{1+x_{n-1}}{2}},\ x_1=0$$
I can easily show that it is increasing, bounded and thus converges with its limit being $1$. But what if I wanted to upper bound $x_{n_0}$ for some fixed $n_0$? This bound should be dependent on $n$. How should I proceed?

Comment: How sharp a bound are you looking for?  Already $x_{14}=0.999999982$

Comment: I think I'm asking whether it is possible to obtain some clever functional bound $f(n)$ on this recursive sequence. I need a bound for a proof and $1$ doesn't cut it, some formula dependent on $n$ would be better, but I do not know whether I can retrieve something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
x_0=\cos \frac{\pi}{2}\\
x_1=\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\\
\vdots\\
x_n=\cos 2^{-n-1}\pi
$$

Comment: Was that a guess given the first two elements or is there some deeper reasoning to your answer?

Comment: I recognized the formula for $\cos  \theta/2$ and just set $x_0=\cos\arccos 0$

Comment: For any $ y\in \Bbb R,$ if $\cos y \ne 1$ then        $1-y^2/2+y^4/24>\cos y>1-y^2/2. $  So     $0<1-x_n=( (y_n)^2/2 )(1-(y_n)^2\delta_n/12) <(y_n)^2/2,$  where $y_n=2^{-n-1}\pi$ and $0<\delta_n<1.$

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is increasing and you probably know it converges, so you can assume that $x_n \approx x_{n-1}$.
\begin{eqnarray}
x_n^2 = 0.5 + 0.5 x_n \\
x_n^2 - 0.5 - 0.5 x_n =0 \\
\to x_n = \frac{1}{4} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{2}}= \frac{1}{4}\pm\frac{3}{4}=1
\end{eqnarray}
This is your upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

If
$x_n 
= \sqrt{\frac{1+x_{n-1}}{2}},\ x_1=0
$,
then
$x_n \to 1$,
so let's look at
$y_n = 1-x_n$.

$1-y_n 
= \sqrt{\frac{1+(1-y_{n-1})}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1+(1-y_{n-1})}{2}}
= \sqrt{1-\frac{y_{n-1}}{2}}
$
so
$1-2y_n+y_n^2
=1-\frac{y_{n-1}}{2}
$
or
$y_n-\frac14 y_n^2
=\frac14 y_{n-1}
$.

Since
$0 \le x_n < 1$,
$0 < y_n \le 1$.
Therefore
$y_n
\le \frac14 y_{n-1}+ \frac14 y_{n}^2
\le \frac14 (y_{n-1}+1)
$
and
$y_n
\ge \frac14 y_{n-1}
$.
From the second,
since
$y_1 = 1$,
$y_n \ge 1/4^{n-1}$.

For an upper bound.
we have
$y_1 = 1,
y_2 \le \frac14(1+1)
=\frac12,
$
and
$y_n \le \frac12$
for $n \ge 2$.

Therefore
$y_n(1-\frac14 y_n)
=\frac14 y_{n-1}
$
so,
for $n \ge 2$,
$y_n
=\dfrac{ y_{n-1}}{4(1-\frac14 y_n)}
\le\dfrac{ y_{n-1}}{4(1-\frac14 \frac12)}
=\dfrac{ y_{n-1}}{4(\frac78)}
=\dfrac{2 y_{n-1}}{7}
$.

Therefore,
for $n \ge 3$,
$y_n 
\le \frac12(2/7)^{n-2}
$.